# What is the correct way to update a ListView continously?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm writing a small application, where I want to check if specific applications are running or not. I created a window, which has a ListView child window, and another child window with a timer, which counts back to 0. I want to countinously check, if either the processes are closed which I monitor, or the time is up. Either way the window should close.

My problem is, that I wanted to create a thread, which monitors the processes, and updates the listview. I have a global variable, `ProcArrayCountDisplay` which holds how many items are currently displayes(are running). 
Since I change this variable in the thread, and monitor it too, so the window can close, obviously something is wrong, because sometimes I get an `Access Violation`

I tried to use `InterlockedIncrement( &ProcArrayCountDisplay );` and `InterlockedDecrement( &ProcArrayCountDisplay );` in the functions, where the struct will be modified, but no luck.

So obiously I am doing something wrong. But how should I do it correctly? And sometimes, the Listview flickers. Can I do something about that?

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
// globals
typedef struct
{
   BOOL bKill;
}PARAMS, *PPARAMS;

struct ProcToDisplay
{
   wchar_t * ProcessName;
   wchar_t * DisplayName;
};
struct ProcToDisplay **ProcArrayDisplay = NULL;
int ProcArrayCountDisplay = 0;

BOOL InitInstance( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow )
{
g_hInst_Main = hInstance;
int Width, Height, xPos, yPos;

Width = 400;
Height = 400;
xPos = ( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN ) / 2 ) - ( Width / 2 );
yPos = ( GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN ) / 2 ) - ( Height / 2 );

g_hWnd_Main = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_TOPMOST, WindowClassName, WindowName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, xPos, yPos, Width, Height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
if ( !g_hWnd_Main )
{
    return FALSE;
}

ShowWindow( g_hWnd_Main, nCmdShow );
UpdateWindow( g_hWnd_Main );

return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
static HBRUSH hbrBackground;

PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
static unsigned ThreadId;
static HANDLE hThread = NULL;
static PARAMS params;

switch ( message )
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccx;
        iccx.dwSize = sizeof( INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX );
        iccx.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;

        if ( !InitCommonControlsEx( &iccx ) )
        {
            // handle error
        }

        g_hWnd_ListView = CreateWindow( WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT, xStartPos, yStartPos, MaxWidth, MaxHeight, hWnd, NULL, g_hInst_Main, NULL );
        if ( !g_hWnd_ListView )
        {
            // handle error
        }

        HWND hWnd_Counter = CreateWindow( WindowClassNameChild, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_LEFT | WS_BORDER, 10, 370, 380, 17, hWnd, NULL, g_hInst_Main, NULL );
        if ( !hWnd_Counter )
        {
            // handle error
        }
        SetTimer( hWnd_Counter, 1, 1000, NULL );

        hThread = ( HANDLE )_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, Thread, &params, 0, &ThreadId );
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
        EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
    }
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        if ( wParam == 1 )
        {
            DestroyWindow( hWnd );
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        params.bKill = TRUE;
        WaitForSingleObject( hThread, 2000 );
        CloseHandle( hThread );
        FreeStruct();
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}
return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ChildCounterWndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch ( message )
{
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );

        if ( ProcArrayCountDisplay == 0 )
        {
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            PostMessage( g_hWnd_Main, WM_CLOSE, 1, 0 );
        }

        RECT clientRect;
        GetClientRect( hWnd, &clientRect );

        //DrawText( hdc, timeString, -1, &clientRect, DT_LEFT | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE );
        ExtTextOut( hdc, 0, 0, TA_LEFT | TA_CENTER | ETO_OPAQUE, &clientRect, timeString, wcslen( timeString ), NULL );

        EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
    }
    break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        InvalidateRect( hWnd, NULL, FALSE );
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        // Destroy the timers. 
        KillTimer( hWnd, 1 );
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}

return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall Thread( void *ArgList )
{
PPARAMS pparams;

pparams = ( PPARAMS )ArgList;

while ( ( !pparams->bKill ) || ( ProcArrayCountDisplay > 0 ) )
{

    // clear previous data
    ListView_DeleteAllItems( g_hWnd_ListView );
    FreeStructDisplay(); // frees the array and decrements ProcArrayCountDisplay


    for ( int i = 0; i < ProcArrayCountQuery; i++ )
    {
        // querys the processes and adds them to the array
        if ( !IsProcessRunning( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->ProcessName, ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->DisplayName ) )
        {
            // IsProcessRunning failed
        }
    }

    if ( ProcArrayCountDisplay == 0 )
    {
        // no package to display
        break;
    }

    // display processes
    InsertListViewItems();
    Sleep( 1000 );
}

_endthread();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your flickering listview is unique. Are you working on a main windows OS or their embedded compact line? I've worked with their embedded line and there are many graphical issues that come with the silverlight framework (including many listview issues). If so, then there is no real solution but to stop using listview since that's all microsoft's implementation.

Comment: @Javia1492: I am working on a main Windows OS. I believe the flickering has something to do, with the way I update the Listview. And it jsut flickers, if a scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going only from what you describe (threads and Access Violation), your data is likely not protected against more than one process (thread) accessing it.  If true, this in turn is likely the reason for your access violation.  Google ***[critical sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***, ***[semaphores](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CE0QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpages.cs.wisc.edu%2F~remzi%2FOSTEP%2Fthreads-sema.pdf&ei=E4A-VfXcFIjooAS60YHgBg&usg=AFQjCNG9j-7XXO3YpRBzogn51SGa-v-V1Q&sig2=6PdFm5NjgGpez4eJICln7w&bvm=bv.91665533,d.cGU)***, ***[mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)***,(these links are just a start) all having to do with implementing thread safety for data that needs to be shared among processes.

Here is an example using Critical Sections ( ***[from HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) )***

This is one of the easiest methods to see and understand.  You basically define a protected logical area.   Only there should shared data be edited. In this example, each time the thread handler function is entered, logic flows into the critical section, data is edited, and then logic flows out of the critical section.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc( LPVOID lpParameter )
{
    ...

    // Request ownership of the critical section.
    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection); 

    // Access the shared resource.

    // Release ownership of the critical section.
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);

    ...
return 1;
}
```

***See the link provided*** *above* for how to create the global (CriticalSection), and how to initialize before use.

Comment: I know i have to use them, I just don't know how :( Could you maybe please show an example?

Comment: Should `InterlockedIncrement` not do the same as Mutexes and semaphores?

Comment: I have no experience with ***[InterlockedIncrement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***.  It appears that in a nutshell it will perform an atomic increment (32bit or 64 bit) boundary specific on a single variable.  It may not be as useful on other data types, such as a struct, or a list type.

Comment: I rewrite my code to use the criticalsection, but no luck. However i noticed something during debugging. The window closes, and after the window has been closed appears the Access vioalation, and the debugger jumps to the thread, to the line `if ( !IsProcessRunning( ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->ProcessName, ProcArrayQuery[ i ]->DisplayName ) )`. So isnt't that possible, that somehow the thread doesn't ends, and tryes to access memory, which has been free()'d?

Comment: Did you put the critical section inside the thread handler function ( ***Thread()*** in your example )?  (This is where it needs to be if that is where the protected data is changed.)

Comment: Yes, i did, exactly as shown in the example. Could that be a problem, that at the program end, i also access (free) that shared resource, and there i don't call the enter and leavecriticalsection?

Comment: I found the problem. My thread is not ending when i signal it. Thank you for your help!